# Quastion regarding PLAIN AUTHENTICATION on IMAP servers

Tags: javascript, authentication, imap

I am trying to understand how plain authentication works on IMAP servers.
I implemented a simple IMAP server in JavaScript(Node.JS).
I tried to login with Mozilla Thunderbird but I can't get past the AUTHENTICATION part of the connection.

This is how the communication between server and client looks like:

```
C: 1 capability
S: * CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 SASL-IR AUTH=PLAIN
S: 1 OK - CAPABILITY completed
C: 2 authenticate PLAIN
S: +
```

And AUTHENTICATE handler so far:

```
function authenticate() {
  socket.write('+ ')
}
```

If I understand correctly Thunderbird should send me a message like this '\0login\0password', but it does nothing, it's stuck on 'Mail for login@127.0.0.1: Sending login information...'

Comment: Are you sending new lines after your responsds?

Comment: Yes I send \r\n after each response but not after the `+` character. As you can see it's just a `socket.write('+ ')` notice the space after the '+'.

Comment: It still needs a new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Responses, even the continuation response, need a new line:

```
socket.write('+ Go ahead\r\n')
```

Comment: Thanks, I have no idea why I fought I don't need the newline at the end, it worked.